# I got some trouble when i opened the xml file in Eclipse ( in Graphical Layout )

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I've downloaded an android app in Google. Some layouts in it be able to view in Graphical Layout and the others are not, example with this Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:camera="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.camera"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.android.camera.PreviewFrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <com.android.camera.FocusRectangle
                android:id="@+id/focus_rectangle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.android.camera.PreviewFrameLayout>
```

And i got these words below :

Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- com.android.camera.PreviewFrameLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the class **PreviewFrameLayout**.Please find it and include it on your package

Comment: O. I'am sorry, i've already got class PreviewFrameLayout in that Package

Comment: Did you put the PreviewFrameLayout in com.android.camera package..?

Answer (score 0):

```
com.android.camera.PreviewFrameLayout

com.android.camera.FocusRectangle
```

you should have above custom classes in your corresponding packages.

```
package com.example.scrollview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class TextScroll extends ScrollView {
    private TextScrollListener scrollListener = null;
    public TextScroll(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public TextScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(TextScrollListener scrollViewListener) {
        this.scrollListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (scrollListener != null) {
            scrollListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

example.xml

```
<com.example.scrollview
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrapcontent"
>
</com.example.scrollview>
```

Comment: PreviewFrameLayout ,FocusRectangle post this two classes